# I am writing a C# code and I want a link from the WhatsApp API to run at the code to send message automatically and I cant find it what should I do?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, whatsapp

I am writing a ASP.net using C# code targeting to send a WhatsApp message when I run it, by browsing a link and this link send a message once browsed. so I started using the WhatsApp cloud API and it provided me with this text but I don't know how to use it. Note:i tried using the link written between the text but it didn't run properly

```
curl -i -X POST `
  https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/104958105698690/messages `
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer EABOoKYETUE4BANvFhvdZAX2udBdrHQ8ZBGJQjX2GJUskGlZCpRf17WZB4Etks1SMA2uGCBZAEl0cZB9Rw57hMpB6CPZCZCU9wIWYZCzsoxGcztZBkJHyNd1A8LZCIq5QFz1h6oLVLeacnpDAG05nhKkli43beAd6pDnrh5sKhnoOsIqzvK7uQXtLgZCENGH7wbUmtKfXOOb6ZAZBq7vA6Om78FVTKb' `
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' `
  -d '{ \"messaging_product\": \"whatsapp\", \"to\": \"\", \"type\": \"template\", \"template\": { \"name\": \"hello_world\", \"language\": { \"code\": \"en_US\" } } }'
```

I have used many API's and it worked properly because they give me a direct link to use in my code unlike WhatsApp API which gives me this text above.

here is the code I am using to send the message but i want a link to put inside HttpWebRequest.Create(" ")

```
            WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(" ");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string urltext = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would highly recommend you reconsider the use of WebRequest, it is firmly stated by MS to not use it for new production. Instead, try using [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) which will allow you to send a `PostAsync` to the endpoint which will use the body of your message and the bearer token to determine the appropriate action to take.

Comment: @ExplodatedFaces can you please tell me how to use the text that WhatsApp API have given me in order to use your recommended method.

Comment: You just need to send a `HttpClient` `PostAsync` request with the proper body containing the message details and the authorization header. [you can find details here from WhatsApp](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/message-templates/creation) *edit malformed url

Comment: @ExplodatedFaces i wrote this string url = "https://localhost:5001/api/Employee/TestSCIMPost?client_id=xyz&grant_type=cc";
            var content = new StringContent("");
            HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PostAsync(url, content);        i get error the name client does not exist in current context

Comment: Working on a quick example right now

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example of how to use an HttpClient to send the data you need to send to the WhatsApp On-Premises Business API. This example is not complete and cannot be directly implemented into production but does show you how to form the post to the WhatsApp API. Do bear in mind you may need to add auth headers and other parts to the request and this is a minimum example that only shows how to form the request itself.

***The URI for the API will be different so this example will always return an error message from Facebook.***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testingapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            //var x will either contain the message ID if needed for
            //future use or it will contain the error message from the server.
            var x = await Task.Run(() => sendMessage());
        }
        static async Task<string> sendMessage()
        {
            try
            {
                var textMessage = "Test message";
                var message = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"preview_url", "false" },
                    { "recipient_type", "individual"},
                    { "to", "whatsapp-id" },
                    { "type", "text"},
                    { "body", textMessage}
                };
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(message);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client
                    .PostAsync("https://example.facebook.com/whatsapp/api/messages/text"
                    , content);
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responseBody;
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                return e.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to respond to a message you will need to implement a similar solution using WhatsApps API to respond to a specific message. [Definitely refer to their documentation for the proper structure of a message to them.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp)

Comment: should i change this part?           {"preview_url", "false" },
                    { "recipient_type", "individual"},
                    { "to", "whatsapp-id" },
                    { "type", "text"},
                    { "body", textMessage}

Comment: On that part you can certainly change it! But thats the basic structure for the message WhatsApp expects on their API for a text message. For example the "to", "whatsapp-id" should be replaced with "to", **actual whatsapp ID of the person you're sending it to**